# Прочитать весь текст из socket asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, сокет, tcp, asyncio

Server Этот код ждет только 1024 байт, потому что больше - не работает:

```
import asyncio


async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(1024)
    data2 = await reader.read(1024)
    writer.write("hello from server".encode())
    await writer.drain()
    writer.close()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(asyncio.start_server(handle_client, 'localhost', 4782))
loop.run_forever()
```

Client Генерация 1024байтов и отправка:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 4782))
sock.sendall(("".join([str(i)[-1:] for i in range(1024)])).encode())
data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()
```

Проблема: сервер замораживает клиент из-за того, что ждет еще 1024 байтов, в библиотеке socket возвращает просто b'', тут же, я не разобрался как это сделать, прошу о помощи.

Answer (score 0):

b'' не всегда обозначает конец передачи особенно если передача не законченна. Для потоков надо обозначить конец передачи обрывом соединения или изобретайте протокол на TLV.

Поведение с которое Вы хотите в асинкио можно получить с помошью [протоколов:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-server)

```
import asyncio


class EchoServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        message = data.decode() # -- пакет прилетевший с sendall, уже эвейтнутый
        self.transport.write("hello from server".encode())
        self.transport.close()


async def main():
    # Get a reference to the event loop as we plan to use
    # low-level APIs.
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    server = await loop.create_server(
        lambda: EchoServerProtocol(),
        '127.0.0.1', 4782)

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Но при больших объемах лучше использовать стримы.